# Can you access the ID of a Control added to an asp page in code-behind

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I am adding nodes to a Treeview in an asp via code-behind.  Is there a way of getting the id of the node after I've added it, example code:

```
e.Node.ChildNodes.Add()
```

How can I grab the id of the Node I'm adding (or added)?  Just to be clear I'm trying to access the id that will be on the item on the page and could be used by client-code.

Code snippet of adding the Nodes:

`Private Sub navTree_TreeNodePopulate(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeEventArgs) Handles navTree.TreeNodePopulate`

`Dim TestNode As New TreeNode
TestNode.Text = "Test"
e.Node.ChildNodes.Add(TestNode)`

but `.add` has no return value

Answer (score 0):

In VB, each `TreeNode` has a collection of child nodes in its `ChildNodes` property. The `Add` method returns void, so that's of no help in identifying the new node from your code behind. Microsoft's docs describe a TreeNode's `Value` property as "a non-displayed value used to store any additional data about the node, such as data used for handling postback events", and give an example of using it to store an ID (follow the link below to see their example)

Something like this might work in your case:

```
//to add the node
Private Sub navTree_TreeNodePopulate(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeEventArgs) Handles navTree.TreeNodePopulate

Dim TestNode As New TreeNode
TestNode.Text = "This is a test node."
TestNode.Value= 123 //your data's ID
e.Node.ChildNodes.Add(TestNode)

//to find the node by its ID later you'll have to loop through the collection and look for `Value == 123`
```

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.value?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately I'm not using any data-binding with the nodes I'm creating, so the `node.DataItem` is returning `nothing`.  Is there another way round it or would I need to create a data-binding for it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure without more code to see what's happening with the new nodes after you add them.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using VB instead of C#, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't think webcontrol TreeNode has a Name Property, this is only on windows controls TreeNode.

Comment: You're right again. I found an example from Microsoft's site that looks like what you're trying to accomplish here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.value?view=netframework-4.8 I'll update my answer above accordingly.